# Execute curl function after sending data with php and ajax

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, curl

I have a form with 5 fields and an anchor as submit buton with ajax. I need to execute a function to retrieve some messages depending on what is inserted in the form. This function retrieves different messages from another host(link) depending on a a phone number and a code. How to use this function when I insert data with php and ajax into database to display the answers from that host(link)?

Here is my code:

**The function that verifies the code:**

```php
function hit_check_code_new($phone, $code){
    $url = 'mycustom_path_not_displayed_for_security_reasons/filejson.php';
    $fields = array(
            'phone' => urlencode($phone),
            'code' => urlencode($code)
    );

    //url-ify the data for the POST
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
    rtrim($fields_string, '&');

    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);

    $what_i_received_from_testmail = json_decode($result,true);   
    if (!isset($what_i_received_from_testmail['Respond'])) return 'Invalid response!';
    if ($what_i_received_from_testmail['Respond'] == 'ACCESDENIED') return 'Error: IP invalid!';
    if ($what_i_received_from_testmail['Respond'] == 'INVALIDPARAMS') return 'Error: invalid input params';
    if ($what_i_received_from_testmail['Respond'] == 'TIMEOUT') return 'Error: SQL is not responding!';
    return $what_i_received_from_testmail['Respond'];
}
```

```php
add_action("wp_ajax_enter_code", "enter_code");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_enter_code", "enter_code");
function enter_code(){
    global $wpdb;


    $code = (isset($_POST['code']))?htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['code'])):'';
    $fname = (isset($_POST['fname']))?htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['fname'])):'';
    $lname = (isset($_POST['lname']))?htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['lname'])):'';
    $phone = (isset($_POST['phone']))?htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['phone'])):'';
    $email = (isset($_POST['email']))?htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['email'])):'';


    if(isset($_POST['code']) && !empty($_POST) && is_user_logged_in()){
        $table = 'tst_contest';
        $data = array(
                'code' => $code,
                'fname'         => $fname,
                'lname'           => $lname,
                'phone'           => $phone,
                'email'           => $email 
        );
        $format = array('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s');
        $success = $wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format );
    }
}
```

And also I have an ajax code that works fine to insert data into database through the last function.

My final question is : **How to implement the first function into the second one to get what I said at the beginning?** Thanks in advance.

**Second ajax as suggested by *Fresher***(I used this in the first ajax succes function):

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: ajaxurl,
  data: {action: 'hit_check_code_new', phone: phone, code: code},
  success: function(msg){
   console.log("SECOND AJAX REQUEST");
    }
 })
```

Comment: call another ajax request inside ajax response and point out the function with your parameters

Comment: Can you give me an example please?!

Comment: why you want to get response from ajax first of all? you can directly call the `hit_check_code_new($phone, $code)` after `$success` variable?

Comment: I tried that. It didn't worked and I don't know why. I want after executing the ajax to use the curl function.

Comment: And also I've updated my question with your first suggestion. That's what you were refering to? I've put the code at the end of my question. Please check. I used that ajax inside the succes function of the first ajax.

Comment: Using ajax I'm getting the following warning: <b>Warning</b>:  Missing argument 2 for hit_check_code_new()

Comment: i tested as a plugin and post you a code to check if it is working properly for your side

Answer (score 0):

See the snippet will help you somehow to resolve

```
<?php
/*
 * Plugin Name: Testing
 *
 */

add_action('wp_ajax_hit_check_code_new', 'curl_response');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_hit_check_code_new', 'curl_response');

function curl_response() {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $ajax_url = 'http://localhost/fantastic/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ajax_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('action' => 'ajaxTester', 'param1' => $_POST['phone'])));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $response;
    exit();
}

add_action('wp_head', 'button_ajax');

function button_ajax() {
    ?>
    <input type="text" name="fresher_text_field" class="fresher_text_field" value="124578989"/>
    <input type="submit" name="fresher_click_me" id="fresher_click_me" value="Submit Me" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function () {
            jQuery('#fresher_click_me').click(function () {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
                    data: {action: 'hit_check_code_new', phone: jQuery('.fresher_text_field').val()},
                    success: function (msg) {
                        console.log(msg);
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
    <?php
}

function handle_ajaxTester() {
    if (isset($_POST['param1']) && $_POST['param1'] != '') {
        echo '<br>Response:<br>';
        print_r($_POST);
        exit();
    }
}

add_action('wp_ajax_ajaxTester', 'handle_ajaxTester');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxTester', 'handle_ajaxTester');
```

**EDIT:**

Please no need to point ajax function directly in your curl code instead do something as i denotes as last function.

```
function hit_check_code_new($phone, $code){
 // Your Code
}

function second_ajax_function() {
 $phone = $_POST['phone'];
 $code = $_POST['code'];
 echo hit_check_code_new($phone,$code);
 exit();

}
```